# Reverse a number without converting it to string in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program in c++ to reverse a number it is ok with a number like 1234 but if am trying to input a number like 5430 it is showing 345 and the same in case the number starting with zero eg: if input 0234 it will show 432.

Can somebody tell me how to handle zeros at starting and ending.

I have to store the number only without converting it to string

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    int lastdigit;
    cin >> n;
    int reverse = 0;
    while(n!=0){
        

        lastdigit = n % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + lastdigit;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    cout << reverse<<endl;
}
```

Comment: If you want that zero displayed, the easiest thing would be to convert the number to a string and print the reversed string.

Comment: @sweenish but I have to store the number only without converting it to string

Comment: You can't store a number with a leading zero and expect it to print.

Comment: In that case, you have to store the number of digits in the original number and use `std::setw` and use `0` as a fill character. As @sweenish mentions, numbers aren't stored with leading zeroes.

Comment: @TedLyngmo can you explain where to use it

Comment: Numbers do not retain information about the way the user has typed them. 234, 0234, 00234 and 00000234 typed by the user will all end up as the same number. If you need to distinguish between these inputs, you cannot read them as numbers.

Comment: Well, are you at least allowed to read the input a *character* at a time?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. yeah you r right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not allowed to use a `std::string` to `std::reverse` the number, you could store the number of digits in the original number and use the I/O manipulators [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`std::setfill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) to add the leading zeroes when you print the reversed number.

Example:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int n = 5430;
    
    int reverse = 0;
    int no_of_digits = 0;
    bool neg = n < 0;
    if(neg) n = -n;

    while(n!=0) {
        ++no_of_digits;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + (n % 10);
        n = n / 10;
    }
    
    std::cout << std::setw(no_of_digits) << std::setfill('0') << reverse;
    
    if(neg) {
        reverse = -reverse;
        std::cout << '-';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
0345
```

Comment: Why not to reverse a string itself? :)

Comment: @Evg :-) OP said that wasn't allowed

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's only working for digits having zero at the end not working for the digits whose having zero at starting

Comment: @Deepak I'm not sure I follow what you mean. If you have trailing zeroes, this will display those after your reversed the number. You can't store leading zeroes in an `int` so your original number can't have leading zeroes.

Comment: @Deepak you will need to handle "leading zeroes" as a special case, since you will hit "n==0" and the loop will break.  I would suggest you need to count the number of digits before converting the input to integer, since that information is lost during the conversion.  So you will need to "cin" to a string, get its length and *then* convert it to integer, as opposed to reading "cin" to an integer.  Don't forget to "accept" Ted's Answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i think but it is good to store starting 0 as 03 means 3 but 30 have its importance of zero at ending

Comment: `do { std::cout << n % 10; n /= 10; } while (n);` looks like another way of doing about the same thing. Just sayin'.

Comment: Yes, if you input `03` into an `int` it will be stored in the same way as if you input `003` and there's no way to distinguish between them.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.I see what you mean. Yes, that's a nice option. Just have to print a `-` if it's negative first. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/P5nz3zxoK) - or perhaps one should put the `-` after the reversed number, [like so](https://godbolt.org/z/5sqGj46fP)

Answer (score 1):

I'd advice you to first convert the number into a string and then reverse it. This is better since string variables can store leading zeros (since they're treated as strings rather than numbers) unlike int variables where leading zeros are ignored (sort of).

If you really want to store it in an int variable then you need to make another variable that will store the number of leading zeros then either generate a string that contains the amount of leading zeros you need and print it or print zeros multiple amount of times using for loop.

In both cases, however, you will need to get the digits seperately or as a string since the leading zeros would be ignored if you take them directly with cin into an int variable or if the number of digits is fixed you can just print zeros as needed since if you get the number 0010 for example the first 2 zeros will be ignored and you will have 10 instead.

Hopefully this helps, and if you need help don't be afraid to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative potential solution that keeps it "as numbers."

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

int main() {
  int num;
  std::cout << "Number: ";
  std::cin >> num;

  // Store individual digits in a stack
  std::stack<int> digits;
  while (num) {
    digits.push(num % 10);
    num /= 10;
  }

  // Dump first stack into new stack, reversing them
  std::stack<int> reversed;
  while (!digits.empty()) {
    reversed.push(digits.top());
    digits.pop();
  }

  // Print and deplete reversed digit stack
  std::cout << '\n';
  while (!reversed.empty()) {
    std::cout << reversed.top();
    reversed.pop();
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

It takes advantage of the `std::stack` data structure, but is cumbersome. As a comparison point, here is my suggestion of using a `std::string`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string num;
  std::cout << "Number: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, num);

  for (auto criter = num.crbegin(); criter != num.crend(); ++criter) {
    std::cout << *criter;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output for either program:

```
Number: 300
003
```

You can probably see why the `std::string` is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

This should sort your issue.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    
    cin>>n; // size of array
    
    int a[n+1]={0};
    
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    cin>>a[i];
    
    for(i=n;i>0;i--)
    cout<<a[i];
    
}
```